# Compilation error whilst reading item in vector in rust rustc(E2077)

Tags: vector, rust

I am attempting to generate the nth term of the fibonacci sequence in order to practice using rust, below is the function that I wrote to try and acheive this:

```rust
fn findTerm(term: i128) -> i128 {
    let mut fibonacci: Vec<i128> = Vec::new();
    fibonacci.push(1);
    fibonacci.push(1);

    while fibonacci.len() < term.try_into().unwrap() {
        fibonacci.push(fibonacci[fibonacci.len() - 1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.len() - 2]);
    }

    println!("{:?}", fibonacci);

    fibonacci[term - 1]
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the type `[i128]` cannot be indexed by `i128`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     fibonacci[term - 1]
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `SliceIndex<[i128]>` is not implemented for `i128`
   = help: the trait `SliceIndex<[T]>` is implemented for `usize`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Index<i128>` for `Vec<i128>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors can only be indexed by integers of type `usize`, that's the size of a pointer (and indexing a vector is roughly equivalent to doing pointer arithmetic). Therefore you need to do:

```rust
fn find_term(term: i128) -> i128 {
    let mut fibonacci = Vec::new();
    fibonacci.push(1);
    fibonacci.push(1);

    while fibonacci.len() < term.try_into().unwrap() {
        fibonacci.push(fibonacci[fibonacci.len() - 1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.len() - 2]);
    }

    println!("{:?}", fibonacci);

    fibonacci[(term - 1) as usize]
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b021e2d7f7e1b58d8e2571077388ee16).

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and I appreciate the explaination of the uzize type.

Comment: @JosephStevens incidentally, I put `as usize` to convert instead of `.try_into()` or other alternatives because I don't know how you want to handle the error case, but keep in mind that `usize` is either an alias of `u64` or `u32` (depending on the target system), so `i128` will not always succeed in becoming a `usize`. Alternatively, you could simply change the type of `term` (for instance, why being a `i128` instead of `u128` in the first place?).

Comment: @BlackBeans First, `usize` is never an alias, it's its own type. Second, it can be `u16` too, and even `u8` for some embedded platforms, and perhaps also `u128` on CHERI although unlikely (depending on whether it is pointer sized or pointer _difference_ sized).